# How can I pass a value from input box to default Edit controller GET method, i.e. allow search box to show Edit view for a single record?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

.NET Core v6
MVC Web App with Entity Framework Core

I scaffolded a database table and it created a "db context", then I scaffolded default Controller and Views.

On the home page, I want to create a search box where you put in the primary key, or id. On submit, I want the value passed to the default Edit controller. Essentially, I want someone to be able to pull up a single record to Edit, if they know the primary key (id).

Here is what I have for a search box

```
<form asp-controller="MyTables" asp-action="Edit">
    <p>
        PIN: <input type="text" name="id" />
        <input type="submit" value="Find" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Here is the default Edit method inside the Controller.

```
// GET: MyTables/Edit/XYZ
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var MyTable = await _context.MyTables.FindAsync(id);
           
            if (MyTable == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(MyTable);
        }
```

When I run this, it doesn't work, but I don't know how to set it up. How can I make this work? The only way I've been able to pull a record is by adding `method="get"` to the form, but then it creates a URL structure using "id" as a parameter like this `localhost/MyController/Edit?id=XYZ`. This structure won't work because I'm unable to save the record when I've navigated to the page in this way.

I appreciate any pointers or ideas.

Thank you

**EDIT AFTER COMMENTS:**
It has been suggested that I could go ahead and use the method="get", thereby selecting the correct record. The URL would be in this format: `localhost/MyController/Edit?id=XYZ`. A proposed solution is to fix my POST action to be able to save the record when using such URL paths. I'm not sure why, but it will only save right now if the URL path is in this format: `localhost/MyController/Edit/XYZ` (no parameter ?id =).

Here is a version of my default POST Edit action in the controller.

```
// POST: MyTables/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, [Bind("...,...,...,...,...,...,PrimaryKeyField")] MyTable myTable)
        {
            if (id != myTable.PrimaryKeyField)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(myTable);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!MyTableExists(myTable.primaryKeyField))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(MyTable);
        }
```

In the Edit view, to initiate the POST action, here's some of the Edit Form markup:

```
@model myApp.Models.MyTable
...
<form asp-action="Edit">
...
<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PrimaryKeyField" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="PrimaryKeyField" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PrimaryKeyField" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
...
<div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
```

The reason I'm saying it won't Save is when I click Submit on the Edit form, it brings up this HTTP error:

```
This localhost page can’t be found. No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:7020/MyTables/Edit
HTTP ERROR 404
```

Comment: *This structure won't work because I'm unable to save the record when I've navigated to the page in this way.* I think it can work, will you include your Edit view and action that actually edits the object?

Comment: When you submit the form, the default method is POST, not GET. You might have a Search action that the form submits to, and enable POST for that action. The search action could verify the requested id exists, and then redirect to your Edit action.

Comment: When the URL is "MyTables/Edit/XYZ", the action for the form is the same. When the URL is "MyTables/Edit/?id=XYZ", the action reverts to /Edit with no id. Therefore if I can get the action to respond to /?id=XYZ, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In the Edit View, I added a reference to the Model.
`@model myApp.Models.MyTable`

In the form, I added a [Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0).
`<form asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id=@Model.PrimaryKeyField>`

This is working.

I noticed in the URL pattern of **/Edit/XYZ**, the form's *asp-action* uses this pattern. I noticed with the URL pattern of **/Edit/?id=XYZ**, the form's action uses **/Edit** with NO ID. Therefore, I figured out a way to add the id to the form's action by using the *asp-route-id* tag helper. The form submits the data properly now.